# Jetson AGX Xavier - mmc_rx_fifo_overflow Meaning

Tags: networking

Currently running JetPack 4.4 - L4T R32.4.3 on a ConnectTech Jetson Xavier AGX. We have our own custom application accepting data on one of the ethernet ports via UDP. Occasionally we’ll notice that our software (which monitors the incoming data) reports missing packets. Looking at the the mmc_rx_fifo_overflow parameter from ethtool -S eth0 we see a direct correlation in this value increasing and the number of packets we see missing from our datastream.

My question, what exactly does this parameter (mmc_rx_fifo_overflow) represent and what could potentially cause it to increase?

Thanks!